# Best method of dynamically setting the height of an DOM element with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I've used both `$('#element').css('height', 10)` and `$('#element').height(10)`. Which method is the better practice? Or do they both change the height in the exact same way?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that with `.css()` you are just specifying the value of the inlined style property whereas `height()` tries to set the height of the box. From **[the docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2)**:

> Note that .height(value) sets the content height of the box regardless
>   of the value of the CSS box-sizing property.

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZAHp/)** for a demonstration of the difference and also have a look at the **[relevant part of the source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.height)**

Answer (score 1):

`.height()` is better between those two (as is), but only because `.css()` isn't supposed to take integers as parameters... it should be `.css('height', '10px')`.

In general, I prefer to use `.css()` because I know exactly what it is going to do (set the element style), whereas `.height()` works in mysterious ways (even if simple, not immediately evident).

Additionally `.css()` allows you to set the height to `'45%'` or `'auto'`, whereas you can't accomplish those things with `.height()`

Comment: If you know you'll be working with pixel values, and only working on width and height, and code simplicity is important, then there's nothing wrong with with() and height()...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there isn't a monumental difference besides the fact that you need to specify 'px' for css(). Like m90 said in the comments (and as you can see in the fiddle they posted), each is affected differently by the border-box property (css() takes the padding into account and includes it in the height while height() does not), so this should also be taken into account when deciding which to use.

The jQuery API also has this to say about height():

```
Note that .height(value) sets the content height of the box regardless of the 
value of the CSS box-sizing property.
```

In regards to speed, I found this: http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-height-vs-method-height/2

Here's another general link: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/width-vs-csswidth-and-height-vs.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [JQuery height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) documentation :

> The difference between .css('height') and .height() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former
>   returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .height()
>   method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a
>   mathematical calculation.

Comment: The question's about setting, not getting.

Comment: this is difference of height() and .css('height') and there is no difference for setting i think